# Google Chrome automatically disables my extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have an extension published in the Chrome Store which some users reported as being disabled without their knowledge.

The users of the extension can install it from either the Chrome Store or from our homepage using [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

My guess is that there is a of problem relating to the inline installation method, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior?

Note: I know Google Chrome disabled hosted 3rd party extensions but as stated we use inline installation.

Comment: Have you recently updated the permissions of your extension?

Comment: @Xan No, we haven't. We are aware that increasing the permissions can disable the extension. Thank you.

Comment: You probably should ask this question in the chromium-extensions Google Group, along with the ID of extension in question.

Comment: I'll do it. Many thanks.

Comment: If your extension's permissions haven't changed recently, then it's probably triggering a crash in Chrome.

Comment: @sowbug Thank for the tip. Do you know if there is some documentation about this?

Comment: It's not something that I'd expect to be explicitly documented, because it's just sensible behavior. Otherwise a bad extension would effectively destroy a user's browser. It's like when a crash during startup causes Windows to restart in Safe Mode. Same idea.