# Google chrome - Extensions being automatically removed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to pack an little extension i made, but chrome keeps removing it as it may have been "installed without my consent". Is there any way to stop this? Thanks!

Note: This is not a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377739/google-chrome-automatically-disables-my-extension) , as my extension is not yet in the chrome store.

Comment: Did you enter Developer Mode?

Comment: Yes, i entered. Currently i'm searching for some kind of configuration or flag, so that i don't have to make changes to the code.

Comment: Did you install it while a private window was open?

Comment: No, i installed it by opening the "extensions" page and placing the .crx i just generated  on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to use packed extensions for anything but very limited testing those days.

Chrome [explicitly forbids installs from sources other than CWS](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html). So you really need to either use it unpacked (if it's only for yourself) or publish it to CWS as unlisted/trusted testers (if it's for a small group of people).

The feature to pack still exists, since enterprise deployments and apps are not subject to these restrictions. 99% likely that you won't be able to use enterprise deployment though.

Comment: I published the app to store and added a few friends to my google group to act as testers. They could find the app on the store but now even after I've removed them from the group the extension still remains installed (although they cant access the app from the link/CSW any more.)

Comment: @Rishav As a developer, you don't have much access to mechanisms of force-uninstalling an extension or app. Google does have one (force-disabling known malicious extensions), but you don't. You can, in principle, publish an update that triggers self-uninstall with `chrome.management.uninstallSelf`, but you can't easily target "people who are no longer testers", and it won't help if people have backup copies of your extension.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I think as of now I will have to implement a different mechanism to check if a user is a tester, and if not- SELF DESTRUCT.